# MySQL slow log data purge

Tags: mysql

I can see there are a lot of records in my mysql slow query log. I have optimized most of the slow queries. I don't want to flush my log. In such case how long does a log entry remain in slow log? Does it stay unless it is overwritten by new queries? or does it get purged after a while?

Answer (score 1):

Those logs stay until you either purge them manually or automatically by logrotation scripts et. al.

In other words, there is no built in mechanism of MySQL server that automatically purges the logs.